# При переходе по якорной ссылке имитировать нажатие кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет!
Есть кнопки, по нажатию на которые появляется различный контент, по механике табов. В футере на небольшое оглавление я повесила якорные ссылки к этим табам, но, логично, что при переходе к якорю кнопка не получает фокус.
Нужно чтоб получала, то есть при переходе по якорю раскрывался нужный контент. Это можно как-то сделать? Сss/js не принципиально, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, с помощью JavaScript/jQuery

1. Добавить уникальный `id` для каждой кнопки, который будет открывать нужный контент.
2. В якорные ссылке добавить `href` с уникальным id кнопки к которой она относится.
3. Через JavaScript либо jQuery искать все якорные ссылки на странице, и для каждой ссылки добавлять обработчик события клика, который при переходе по ссылке будет находить нужную кнопку и нажимать её

**Реализация через JavaScript:**

```
// Get all anchor links on the page
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');

// Add event listener for each anchor link
anchors.forEach(function (anchor) {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior of the link
        
        // Get the id of the button to which the anchor link is related
        const targetId = this.getAttribute('href');

        // Find the target button by its id
        const targetButton = document.querySelector(targetId);

        // If the button is found, click it
        if (targetButton) {
            targetButton.click();
        }
    });
});
```

**Реализация через jQuery:**

```
// Add event listener for each anchor link
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior of the link

    // Get the id of the button to which the anchor link is related
    const targetId = $(this).attr('href');

    // Find the target button by its id
    const targetButton = $(targetId);

    // If the button is found, click it
    if (targetButton.length) {
        targetButton.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, мил человек!

Comment: А можно сделать то же самое, но не для button, а для div?